# How does git config --global --edit open vi in cmd.exe

Tags: windows, git, vi

What I want to know is how to use the editor (vi?) that `git config --global --edit` opens for other files.  I see that there is a vi "file" in the Git\bin directory but its not a runnable file as far as windows is concerned.

I can cheat by opening the editor using the git config command and then using :e to open other files, but surely there must be a way to get the editor open without using that workaround.

This is all for using inside cmd.exe, on windows 7 and/or 8.

Comment: You could use vim through the bash shell shipped with Git. It works out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [latest git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) (like [the 2.9 one](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.9.0.windows.1)) does include `vim.exe`.

```
vonc@ D:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit\usr\bin
> dir vi*
 Volume in drive D is data

 Directory of D:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit\usr\bin

15/02/2016  19:12                25 vi
09/04/2016  07:08         2 335 971 vim.exe
```

`vi` is just a shell wrapper to call `vim`:

```
vonc@ D:\prgs\git\PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit\usr\bin
> more vi
#!/bin/sh

exec vim "$@"
```

As long as `<path/to/2.9>/usr/bin` is in your `%PATH%`, you can call `vim` on any file (within or outside a git repo, it does not matter).

[image: vim]

Comment: I don't know what directory I was looking in, but it wasn't /usr/bin.  Found it, got it working.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

core.editor
By default, Git uses whatever you’ve set as your default text editor ($VISUAL or $EDITOR) or else falls back to the vi editor to create and edit your commit and tag messages. To change that default to something else, you can use the core.editor setting:

$ git config --global core.editor emacs
Now, no matter what is set as your default shell editor, Git will fire up Emacs to edit messages.

Vi tutorial? Google for it, or just follow one of the many on the web like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-vi-editor.htm